# Calling 2D C Arrays from Swift

Tags: c, arrays, swift, pointers

I have a C function that operates on 2D arrays.

I want to interact with this C function from Swift.

I try; however, I get an error. I am pasting the relevant code.

Thanks!

```
///// C Code

#include "test.h"

void test(int N, int J, double arr[J][N], double arr2[J][N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr2[J][i] = arr[J][i];
    }
}

///// C Header

#include <stdio.h>

  void test(
         int N, int J, double arr[J][N], double arr2[J][N]);


  ///// Call from Swift

  let a = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
 let arr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Any>.allocate(capacity: 1)
  arr.initialize(to: a) // intialize with a value
  let arrs = OpaquePointer(arr)


  let a2 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
  let arr2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Any>.allocate(capacity: 1)
  arr2.initialize(to: a2) // intialize with a value
 let arrs2 = OpaquePointer(arr2)

 let j = a.count

  let n = a[0].count

  test (Int32(n), Int32(j), arrs, arrs2)

 let yiii = UnsafeMutablePointer<Any>(arrs2)

let yii = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: yiii, count: n))

 print(yii) // Trying to get values (ans)

 // Throws error:
```

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8)

Comment: You should paste your error into the question.

Comment: The C code is buggy to start with, so you should fix that before trying to call it from Swift - you’re trying to access both arrrays outside their bounds.

Comment: @Lundin: OP is reading/writing row index J, but the array dimension is J.

Comment: Oh right. Yeah that's a very obvious bug! :) (time to get more coffee)

Comment: Voting to close this as simple typo then.

Comment: I suspect we’re not seeing the actual code, but who knows - a [mcve] is needed.

Comment: @PaulR: That is *one* issue, but not the only one. The real problem that Swift has no "2D arrays" which are layout-compatible to C. So this is not just a "simple typo" problem.

Comment: @MartinR: thanks, yes, I was wondering about that: accessing 2D C VLAs seemed to be a big ask, but I don’t know much about Swift.

Comment: Note that in C the size of a 2D (or higher) array has to be fixed or the compiler can't do the address calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize: Swift does not have an equivalent of C n-dimensional arrays. You can create nested arrays of arrays, but if your goal is to manipulate shared memory structures that map to a C-style 2D array you will have to create a 1D array that maps to a memory buffer and do the indexing math yourself.

Alternately, you can link C/Objective-C code in with your Swift program and just leave your code in C.

Comment: Thanks to all! Yes, no provision to trade 2D arrays between Swift & C. So, I ended up using 1D Swift arrays and doing the bulky processing using 1D C arrays. A little complicated since I had some nested for loops in Swift, but it worked out for me :)